# Is it possible to use webbrowser or Selenium to grab current URL in browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, python-webbrowser

Or perhaps "hack" the actual library code for [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html) to do this? I'm looking in the current documentation and not seeing that this is possible, but perhaps you could adjust the actual library code and insert this functionality?

Unfortunately, the following approach with Selenium doesn't work - it only returns the original URL:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a387355f&redirect_uri=http://pythondev.instadev.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code")
print driver.current_url
```

Comment: This may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242340/selenium-get-current-url-after-loading-a-page

Answer (score 3):

No, but if you're looking for a module that gives you more control over the browser look into selenium webdriver.

In selenium the function is [driver.current_url](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url)

as the bob0the0mighty's link shows, you'll need to have a loop that waits for the url to change. try something like: 
`initialurl="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/client_id=cb0096f08a387355f&redirect_uri=http://pythondev.instadev.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code"`

`currenturl="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a387355f&redirect_uri=http://pythondev.instadev.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code"`

`while(true):
    if(currenturl != initialurl):
        print currenturl
        break`

Comment: That just returns the initial URL I've called, not the redirect

Answer (score 2):

The python webbrowser module launches an external process that is different depending on platform and even environment variables on that platform.  So I'd say in general "no".