# issue with sendKey inside if statement

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working on an auto login using Selenium. I'm able to open the browser and enter and submit the username just fine, but after entering the username, it will sometimes ask you to enter your secret question answer. for whatever reason, it just refuses to enter the secret question answer. oddly enough, it will also occasionally tell me it's unable to locate the element of the text box, but other times it will run and never give the error. Everything seems to work fine up until the if statement, and then it all falls apart.

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String  expectedURL = "https://mblogin.verizonwireless.com/amserver";


        driver.get("https://sso.verizonenterprise.com/amserver/sso/login.go");


        WebElement userId = driver.findElement(By.name("userId"));


        userId.sendKeys("username");


        userId.submit();

        if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(expectedURL)){
             WebElement answer = driver.findElement(By.name("answer"));

             answer.sendKeys("test");
             answer.submit();


        } 





    }
}
```

The if statement itself should be fine, as I have been able to test it by outputting messages to the console, but it doesn't seem to want to fill in the text box and submit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try *waiting for URL to change with a custom Expected Condition* provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242994/771848).